# Getting parserError when calling controller using ajax and set data in datatable in mvc project

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in mvc and i got the parserError when i call the controller using ajax and want to set list using datatable. but i don't know what i am doing wrong here.

when try to debug then i was not got my self in controller.

After i searched i found that use datatype:'text' but that don't want it.

I want only json data and want to set using data table.

but don't know what i doing wrong here.

Any one have idea, let me share here.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <table id="userGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Zipcode</th>
                    <th>IsAdmin</th>
                    <th>IsFirstTimeLoggedIn</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>


@section Scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/User/UserList",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("failure:"+response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        debugger
                        alert("Error:"+response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                $("#userGrid").DataTable(
                    {
                         "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        "searching": false,
                        "ordering": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "processing":true,
                        data: response,
                        columns: [{ "data": "Email" },
                        { "data": "Password" },
                        { "data": "Zipcode" },
                        { "data": "IsAdmin" },
                        { "data": "IsFirstTimeLoggedIn" }]
                    });
            };
        </script>
    }


public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<User> users = _userService.GetAllUsers().ToList();
            return Json(new { data = users }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.ErrorFormat("Error in get user list. Error : {0}", ex.Message);
            _log.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want only json data and want to set using data table

Since the json format returned by the UserList method contains **`data`** before the users , you need to obtain the returned data collection through **`response.data`** in the success method of ajax.

On the other hand, because you get the data in the success method (not directly through ajax), you need to **comment out the `"serverSide": true` statement**.

Here is the example:

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
                $("#userGrid").DataTable(
                    {
                         "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        "searching": false,
                        "ordering": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        // "serverSide": true,
                        "processing":true,
                        data: response.data,
                        columns: [{ "data": "Email" },
                        { "data": "Password" },
                        { "data": "Zipcode" },
                        { "data": "IsAdmin" },
                        { "data": "IsFirstTimeLoggedIn" }]
                    });
            };
```

Here is the test result:

[image]